# Slow SQL backup to local disk problem, with odd workaround

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2017

I have some SQL Server 2017 (14.0.3037) servers, both Standard Edition and Developer Edition, running on Windows Server 2016 Standard in a VMware environment (v6.5).  The disks are on fast SAN storage

**Disk config:**

**C:** OS, incl. swapfile
  **D:** SQL program files, system db and SQL Backup
  **E:** DB Data
  **F:** DB Tlog
  **G:** TempDB

The problem is that we see very slow SQL backups.  On a 50 GB database that normally took 2 minutes to backup, now it takes 77 minutes.

When there is enough free space on the disk for a compressed backup, and the backup can complete.   But if there is too little free space the backup is very slow.

But I found a strange workaround...
During the backup, if I find that it is running slow, (by measuring MB/sec on the data disk), if I then delete a big file, the backup speeds up immediately, the performance (MB/sec on the data disk) goes up, and the backup is fast.

So now I have expanded the disk so it has more free space, and the backup is fast.

I see this as a workaround, not a solution, so I would like to hear if anyone has seen this problem?  If anyone has more info about why the SQL backup runs very slow if SQL Server thinks that there is not enough free space on the disk...

Is this a new SQL 2017 feature?

Edit:
This is also happens on SQL 2016, and probably from 2008 and up...

Microsoft has released a info about how much a compressed SQL Backup pre-allocate when backup starts, it is 1/3 of the reserved data in a database:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2001026/inf-space-requirements-for-backup-devices-in-sql-server

Comment: Are you backing up to disk E? If so, have you got any performance monitor / disk statistics for the period of the backup?

Comment: Perhaps file system fragmentation. A 64K allocation unit size may help.

Comment: Did you try trace flag 3042 (skips the large pre-allocation of the backup file)? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3626/testing-sql-server-backup-performance-with-trace-flag-3042/

Comment: Some storage will become slower when it has very little free space.

Comment: @George.Palacios I am normally backing up to D-drive, but this problem is on any drive i backup to, if there is not 'enough' free space, it do slow backup.

Comment: @DanGuzman 64K allocation do not help, it exist on both 4K and 64K allocation drives.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi I have now tried T3042, and the backup is slow if it is off, and the pre-allocation can't get what it normally get durring a backup with compression. if T3042 is on, there is no pre-allocation and no slow backup.
But I don't understand why?

Comment: Perhaps you have a high compression ratio meaning it pre-allocates much more than it needs in the end. And this huge pre-allocation gets to closer to disk capacity and you experience slowness when you get close to disk capacity. And/or file system fragmentation comes into play, again being more severe getting closer to disk capacity.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi as I have it on several SQL servers with different database, even on db where the pre-alloc and final size is the same. also it is not file fragmentation, as i can delete/create 200MB file before or durring the backup, i can control if the backup speed is fast or slow. (and disk has 0% fragmentation)

Comment: When the pre-alloc and final size is the same, then this option shouldn't help, but rather hurt you. My theory is that in this case the pre-alloc is larger than final size, and you hit near-capacity of disk, hence the slowness. Removing the pre-allocation did obviously help you (as I read an earlier comment), so why not just run it with that trace flag? Or allocate more storage. Those two, seems to me, are your two options.